# To scan for ports and to list the services running on each port

Tags: java, service

I am trying to build a port scanner which not only scans for port numbers but, also list the services running on the respective port .I am new to java-programming and As you can see i have the code for scanning the status of ports on the local machine. I don't know where to start when it comes to list services running on each port. I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me any code/links to list those services. Thanks for the help.....

```
public class port {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "localhost";
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        String hostName = inetAddress.getHostName();

        for (int port = 0; port <= 200; port++) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                String text = hostName + " is listening on port " + port;
                System.out.println(text);
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                String s = hostName + " is not listening on port " + port;
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those who took trouble the trouble to go through this,i am grateful ,u guys really helped me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are looking for something like [`Nmap`](http://nmap.org/)?

Your code seems good to me, although I would do something like

```
public class PortScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String host = "localhost";
        final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        final String hostName = inetAddress.getHostName();
        final List<int> openPorts = new ArrayList();

        // we begin at port 1 because port 0 is never used
        for (int port = 1; port <= 200; port++) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                openPorts.add(port);
            } catch (IOException) {
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot easily know what service is running on the port, you can only simply assume what service is running on that port using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) list. But beware, a web server can use custom ports instead of default ones.

If you do have the requirement to know exactly what service is running on what port, I suggest you use [`Nmap`](http://nmap.org/) and make a bash script out of it which in turn outputs it's findings in a `.txt` file. That `.txt` file can then be read by Java. This approach saves tons of work.

Comment: This information really helped me a lot ,Thanks,i can always count on you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine if you want to check for open ports, but identifying services... well, that's tricky.

It's a bit like identifying the type of file by reading the first few bytes. An easy solution is to compare the port number with the [list of well known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). So if port 80 is open, you just assume it's HTTP and move on.

This method assumes that services actually listen on their assigned ports. This is like assuming that a file that ends with "zip" is always a zip file. It's correct most of the time, but only because it's a convention. Not because it has to be this way. If you want to actually fingerprint services - determine the type of service by "talking to it", then it's a serious undertaking, not something that can be explained in a few lines. I suggest you take a look at [Nmap](http://nmap.org/), as it's an existing tool that does just that. You might be able to use it instead of writing your own.

Comment: i had thought about it, but in a vague manner. After hearing you i suppose i should assume the services. u really helped me out, Thx